# Create a custom context menu on text selection in WebView

Tags: android, webview, contextmenu

I have a WebView in my app and I want to display a custom context menu on text selection as below:

[image]

I don't want to use Android's Context ActionBar. I want a very small context menu in place of action.

What should I do?

Comment: try: [link](https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/9345938)

Comment: Would you please provide more details on how to use this library class?